# Diffrent package name and bundle id

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

My flutter app is already published on playstore. And now the bundle id is not available error on xcode when build and publish ips app.
Is it possible to set up Different package name and bundle id for a flutter app

Firebase in android working very well. And I tried to set up firebase push notification in iOS with slightly changed bundle id, everything look okay, but firebase messages not received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Use following steps:
Xcode-> Runner -> Target -> Runner -> Bundle Identifier

Change the bundle identifier to something else. Now, head over to firebase and add iOS app with this bundle identifier. You will have to set push notification for iOS in case you are going to use firebase for iOS push notification.

https://docs-assets.developer.apple.com/published/e7484edae7/3376276@2x.png

Comment: i do all procedure including the above. and i got output with a areal ios device: APNS device token not set before retrieving FCM Token for Sender ID '**************'. Notifications to this FCM Token will not be delivered over APNS.Be sure to re-retrieve the FCM token once the APNS device token is set.
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s): iOS settings must be set when targeting iOS platform.

Comment: You should look how to set up notification in iOS app with Flutter. There are few steps involved which you will need to take care of.